# Access dropbox from inside AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, dropbox, amazon-ecs

I've tried connecting to dropbox account from my AWS ECS instance as specified in this [1] article, but unfortunately I noticed there is a permission problem. The user that I'm using has permission to everything, all out ports are open. Below I've pasted log of failed daemon start.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-179-221-31 ~]$ ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
Couldn't start Dropbox.
This is usually because of a permissions error. Storing your home folder on a network share can also cause an error.

Get more help at https://www.dropbox.com/c/help/permissions_error

Please contact Dropbox support with the following info for help:

/tmp/dropbox_errorTC7IXY.txt
```

Is there a way to use Dropbox on AWS?

[1] http://ged.msu.edu/angus/tutorials-2011/installing-dropbox.html

Comment: Did you check this http://webdeveloperpadawan.blogspot.com/2012/07/dropbox-integration-with-ec2-linux.html

Comment: @error2007s it's basically the same instruction as I gave. It's just downloading the daemon and running it. Same result - permissions error.

Comment: Run this two commands "sudo chown -R yourUsername /Users/yourusername/Dropbox" and "sudo chmod -R 700 /Users/yourusername/Dropbox" and see if it works

Comment: @error2007s Nope. Still didn't work...

Comment: `cat /tmp/dropbox_errorTC7IXY.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, that it was just a locale problem. The solution is to set `LC_ALL` and `LANG` env variables:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-111-184-40 ~]$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
[ec2-user@ip-10-111-184-40 ~]$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```